# How to use a response handler for promise results

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, httpresponse

I have two methods that have a common response logic and I tried to extract that response logic to another method and link to all promises, but did thrown errors:

**Original methods:**

```
  method1: function (req, res) {
    db.getData(req)
      .then(data => {
          res.status(200).send({ status: 200, data: data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send({ status: 500, statusText: error.message })
      })
  },
  method2: function (req, res) {
    db.getData2(req)
      .then(data => {
          res.status(200).send({ status: 200, data: data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send({ status: 500, statusText: error.message })
      })
  },
```

**What I tried to do?**
(Extract the response promise to another common method)

```
responseMethod: function (promise) {
    promise
      .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send({ status: 200, data: data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send({ status: 500, statusText: error.message })
      })
  },
  method1: function (req, res) {
    responseMethod(db.getData(req))
  },
  method2: function (req, res) {
    responseMethod(db.getData2(req))
  },
```

**Error:**

```
Reference Error: responseMethod is not defined
```

Comment: The error you see is with the attempt to stringify the object, and nothing to do with the asynchronousness (though, note that you should *return* `Promises`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I know, and I don't understand why this error message, so I need to find a solution in this scenario, do you have idea how?

Comment: First figure out which line the error is being thrown at, and then look at that line's methods and the object that the method uses - sounds like it's circular.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok, I identified it is: ReferenceError: responseMethod is not defined when I call the responseMethod

Comment: Ok, that's a completely different error. Your `responseMethod` is a *property of the parent object*, not a standalone function, so `responseMethod(...` won't work. Don't know the calling context, but try `this.responseMethod(...`

Comment: Looks like, now the error is with the res parameter, I passed it through the responseMethod and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix this scenario:

**Answer below:**

> **fix #1:** res as a parameter in the responseMethod
>
> **fix #2**: return of the promise in the responseMethod

```
responseMethod: function (res, promise) {
    return promise
      .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send({ status: 200, data: data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send({ status: 500, statusText: error.message })
      })
  },
  method1: function (req, res) {
    responseMethod(res, db.getData(req))
  },
  method2: function (req, res) {
    responseMethod(res, db.getData2(req))
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

> Reference Error: responseMethod is not defined

Your error has to do with the `this` keyword in javascript, not any of the async stuff.

```js
const containerObj = {
  responseMethod: function() {
    return 'ok'                  // simplified for testing
  },
  method1: function() {
    return this.responseMethod() // succeeds because it references 'this' object
  },
  method2: function() {
    return responseMethod()      // fails because you need to reference 'this'
  },
}

/* TESTS */
console.log(containerObj.method1()) // should succeed
console.log(containerObj.method2()) // should fail
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers,